# How to store an item in a firebase list at a specific position

Tags: javascript, list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list like this:

```
{ 
  randomFirebaseGeneratedUID: {position: 0, someData: ''},
  randomFirebaseGeneratedUID: {position: 1, someData: ''},
  randomFirebaseGeneratedUID: {position: 2, someData: ''},
  randomFirebaseGeneratedUID: {position: 3, someData: ''},
  randomFirebaseGeneratedUID: {position: 4, someData: ''},
}
```

Now I would like to add a new Item, e.g., in between position 1 and 2

I have difficulties in finding a clean and proper way to do that. What I came up with currently is this:

```
export const addAtListPositionHelper = (list, payload) => {
  Object.keys(list)
    .filter(key => list[key].position > payload.position)
    .forEach(key => {
      list[key].position = list[key].position + 1
    })
  list.push().set(payload)
  return list
}

export function addAtListPosition(contentId, payload) {
  const db = getFirebaseInstance().database()
  db.ref(`${contentId}`).transaction(list => addAtListPositionHelper(list, payload))
}
```

The payload would look like: `{p: 2, someData: ''}`

The problem with this is that I can't push the payload like it is written in the code as the list is actually an object and the id's of those objects are generated UIDs from firebase.

Of course I could generate the UID on my own, but it looks like kind of messy to me to have some UIDs generated by firebase and some by my own.

Another way I was thinking of was about to push the item first and then do the ordering, but that could lead to inconsistent data for a short time.

Is there really no better way to deal with what I think is a pretty common usecase?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds messy and is wrought with race conditions right now. Re-indexing is in an expensive operation on any database, and especially so on Firebase due to its NoSQL/Realtime nature.

The only way I can quickly think of is to use a transaction on the entire list. That will work, but will badly hurt the scalability of this code.

The problem stems from the fact that you want your positions to be sequential integers, something that is hard to scale. In fact, one of the oldest Firebase blog posts recommends precisely against that: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

So to make this operation more scaleable, you'll have to move away from the positions being sequential integers. I know of two approaches:

1. Make them non-sequential
2. Make them non-integers

:-)

#### Make them non-sequential

An alternative is to leave room for inserting items when you generate a new document. E.g. if you space the indices out like this:

```
{ 
  randomFirebaseGeneratedUID: {position: 0, someData: ''},
  randomFirebaseGeneratedUID: {position: 10, someData: ''},
  randomFirebaseGeneratedUID: {position: 20, someData: ''},
  randomFirebaseGeneratedUID: {position: 30, someData: ''},
  randomFirebaseGeneratedUID: {position: 40, someData: ''},
}
```

Then the item between 10 and 20, can just get position 15. This is actually quite common, and drastically reduces the need to re-index all items.

#### Make them non-integers

If your positions can be non-integer numbers, you'll never have to reindex. Inserting an item between 1 and 2 is then a simple 1.5. And with the resolution of floating point numbers, you're unlikely to run out of "positions" any time soon.

That's actually the approach I've taken recently when I needed to move/reorder/insert documents.